# sort a list of dictionary by taking integer value of keys stored as string

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries with values stored as strings. I want to sort them by taking the values as integer not string.
 Code I have

```
 XWordDict=[{"name":"ABC","pos":"1"},{"name":"GHI","pos":"10"},{"name":"DEF","pos":"2"}]
Xlistsorted=sorted(XWordDict,key=(operator.itemgetter("pos")))
```

This gives the order as

```
[{'name': 'ABC', 'pos': '1'}, {'name': 'GHI', 'pos': '10'}, {'name': 'DEF', 'pos': '2'}]
```

however I want it to be

```
 [{'name': 'ABC', 'pos': '1'}, {'name': 'DEF', 'pos': '2'}, {'name': 'GHI', 'pos': '10'}]
```

If I change to

```
Xlistsorted=sorted(XWordDict,key=int(operator.itemgetter("pos)))
```

it gives an error

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'operator.itemgetter'
```

Comment: if you want order use an OrderedDict, you also cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: Your example dictionary isn't valid Python code, try to put together something that people can copy-paste into their console easily (test it by copy-pasting into *your* console).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `key` argument needs to be a function. `operator.itemgetter(i)` returns a function, but in order to add extra processing on top of that, you'll have to use a lambda. Because `itemgetter` returns a function, you can call the result to use it on the dictionary (which you are passing as the `x` in the lambda:

```
listsorted = sorted(XWordDict, key=lambda x: int(operator.itemgetter("pos")(x)))
listsorted
Out[16]: 
[{'name': 'ABC', 'pos': '1'},
 {'name': 'DEF', 'pos': '2'},
 {'name': 'GHI', 'pos': '10'}]
```

That said, `itemgetter` might be an overly complex solution here, you can just do:

```
listsorted = sorted(XWordDict, key=lambda x: int(x['pos']))
```

Comment: `x.get('pos',0)` would be better in case `'pos'` doesn't exist in the dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

The argument to sorted()'s "key" keyword is a unary function that returns the actual value you want sorted. So you'll need a function that converts each element of the list (the dictionary which we'll call d), accesses the value you want to sort on, and converts it from a string to an integer.

```
def dict_to_int(d):
    string_value = d['pos']
    int_value = int(string_value)
    return int_value
```

You would pass this to sorted() like this:

```
sorted_list = sorted(list_of_dicts, key=dict_to_int)
```

This function is a verbose example, and can be shortened significantly and converted to a fairly concise lambda:

```
lambda d: int(d['pos'])
```

and used thus:

```
sorted_list = sorted(list_of_dicts, key=lambda d: int(d['pos']))
```

Comment: Your definition of `dict_to_int` is incorrect: the last line should read `return int_value`.